# Mount another virtual hard disk always belongs root owner, why?

Tags: linux

Environment is in virtual box,ubuntu 12.04. It has 2 disks, `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` are both ext4 type filesystem.

Since `/dev/sdb1` is add after system installed, so I want to mount it manually. I'd try this command:

```
sudo mount -o user,defaults /dev/sdb1 ~/project
```

No errors report. Then I get mount info by `mount`:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /home/igsrd/project rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev
```

But when I `ls -l` to see `/home/igsrd` I found its permission is still belongs `root`, so I can't touch anything in it. **Why it still belongs root?**

I have another machine running ubuntu 12.04,too. I mount another partition with same option will be fine, correct permission(ownership). Are any differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

*nix permissions on a filesystem that supports them natively, e.g. ext4, will be maintained regardless of how it is mounted when using a proper filesystem driver, e.g. the native ext4 driver built into Linux.

Comment: So, can I mount it with custom owner? I want it be mounted with my ownership, not root.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it isn't a correct behavior.
Files all have its original ownership, I shouldn't change them because I want to mount it to my system. If I want to mount it to other's system, would I change them again?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just  (while still root) do this:

```
chown -R <your-user-name> ~<your-user-name>/project
```

?